# Sort list of procedures in Structure pane

Tags: sorting, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I recently moved to Delphi 11.1 Enterprise Edition.  I notice the list of procedures in the Structure Box for the form are not sorted as they were in Delphi XE3.  I can't find a way to sort the list of procedures for each form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools|Options|User Interface|Explorer|Explorer sorting

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know if I would have ever found the path.